# Как сделать слайдер с помощью перспективы css/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Кто может подсказать лучшее решение для такой задачи? Мне нужно сделать слайдер, чтобы листался экран на моб. телефоне

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На css это можно реализовать, но вот смотрю на поддержку браузеров, и думаю что не очень подойдет такой вариант. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=perspective)

Может кто то сталкивался с таким? Может есть плагины, или пример какой-то.
Нужна поддержка последних версий браузеров

Comment: Опишите задачу более подробно, приведите пример разметки `html`. Что вы пробовали и что не получается.

Comment: Вопрос в том, какими средствами лучше всего такое делать

Comment: Вопрос в том, что именно надо сделать и как оно должно работать. Одной картиночки далеко недостаточно.

Comment: по клику на стрелки листать картинку на экране телефона, картинка должна быть в `perspective` такой же, как телефон

Comment: Вам нужно скачать в инете слайдер готовый с поддержкой касания с таким функционалом Самом писать слайдер невыполнимая задача

Comment: Ну так уж прям невыполнимая?

Comment: Пример похожего слайдера: https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TiltedContentSlideshow при реализации подобных слайдеров рекомендую использовать fallback с помощью css @supports или js библиотек

Comment: Если не хотите использовать CSS для трансформации, то вам надо сделать обычные картинки, на которых изображение уже будет повернуто так, как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста

```js
var a = 0;
var img = document.getElementById("img")
var images = ["https://www.pravmir.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/1609426-600x337.jpg", "https://bigpicture.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DtZhozyvpFQ-800x642.jpg"];

function pre() {
  if (a == 0) a = 1;
  else a--;
  img.src = images[a];
}

function next() {
  if (a == 1) a = 0;
  else a++;
  img.src = images[a];
}
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
}
button {
    margin-top:30px;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<button class "left" onClick="pre()">Назад</button>
<img src="https://www.pravmir.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/1609426-600x337.jpg" class="left" id="img" width="100" height="100" />
<button class="left" onClick="next()">Вперёд</button>
```

Comment: Даже длину массива не мерял Красавчик!!

Comment: Разложил предыдущего оратора на молекулы!!!

Comment: Вопрос вообще не в этом, как слайдер повернуть (x, y, z) 3d, если css свойства не все раузеры поддерживают?